# Cross Border Canada with B1/B2 Visa

Tags: canada

I have Visitor Visa B1/B2 it's valid for five more months I would like to visit Canada as well please let me know the requirement documents that i must have with myself to enter to Canada.

like: Passport and B1/B2 Visa.
      I-94 form 
      what else required ?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Are you asking if B1/B2 visa is sufficient for you to enter Canada?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: B1/B2 visa is for entering the USA.  If you plan to enter Canada, then you need to identify what visa requirements apply to you based on your citizenship.  If you generally need a visa to enter Canada, then you need to get that visa, regardless of any USA visa or how you would be entering Canada.

Comment: Dear Flimzy I am From Afghanistan. the only thing that I am concern about single entry and double entry to United States.

Answer (score 2):

You will need separate permission to enter Canada, regardless of whether you have a visa for the US. [This Government of Canada page will tell you if you need a visa, and what kind, based on your nationality and purpose of visit](http://www.cic.gc.ca/englisH/visit/index.asp). In general you will need a visitor visa for Canada if you required a visa for the US, but there are exceptions.

Comment: Yes... I am From Afghanistan

Comment: @user17271 you'll need a separate visa http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp